# Connect/read BluetoothLE devices with password in ngCordova/Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ngcordova

I'm using https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/ firstly to scan devices and later to connect/read/write data in them.

The devices that i have to connect with are password protected but there is no input or parameter to include it.

I made the connection with the devices (without password) and everything seems to be OK but attempt to read data from the different devices is imposible.
The read data is encoded (base64) and after converting it to a String the result is " "
Any hint about this?

Connection:

```
$rootScope.connect = function(addressParam) {
var params = {address: addressParam};

$cordovaBluetoothLE.connect(params).then(null, function (obj) {
  console.log("Conexión error " + obj.status + " con dirección: " + obj.address);
  $rootScope.close(addressParam);
}, function (obj) {
  console.log("Conexión success " + obj.status + " con dirección: " + obj.address);
  $rootScope.isCon(addressParam);
  if(obj.status==="disconnected" || obj.status==="undefined" ){
    $rootScope.connect(addressParam);
  }
});
}
```

Read:

```
$scope.readChar = function(){
  var params = {address: $scope.device, service: $scope.service.uuid, characteristic: $scope.characteristic, timeout: 5000};
  $cordovaBluetoothLE.read(params).then(function(obj) {
    $scope.leer = true;
    console.log("COMENZANDO LECTURA ");
    $scope.valueobj = obj.value;
    $scope.convertValue();
  }, function(obj) {
    console.log("Error al leer" + obj);
  });
}
```

Conversion after reading

```
$scope.convertValue = function(){
  $scope.bytesobj = $cordovaBluetoothLE.encodedStringToBytes($scope.valueobj);
  $scope.strobj = $cordovaBluetoothLE.bytesToString($scope.bytesobj);
}
});
```

Results: No error:

$scope.bytesobj
--> [0, 0]

$scope.strobj
--> "

$scope.valueobj
--> "AAA="

Comment: Have you find any solutions, I am trying with ionic 4 but not working